# Jquery mobile popup refresh page after the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a question, i generate a page with a javascript code and i use popup. This page works great but :
     - When i open a popup for the first time, i can close it and it's works normally
     - When u open a popup for the second time, i can close it but the page is refresh after this one was closed.

I don't understand why it's happen only after the second closed. I really want to be unable to close how often i want my popup. If someone have an idea to solve this problem please tell me.
Thanks you for all your contribution to my probleme.

nb : i have already try to set the history option to false of jquery mobile popup.

Comment: code, version, model, etc.

Comment: Sorry : last version and I post a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/76tHv/

Comment: a fiddle isn't enough, you need to elaborate on the problem. Btw, _popup_ div shouldn't be wrapped in any container.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle and now you can see the probleme : when you click one time on "abandonner" and in "non" the popup close normally but when you click a second time on it the popup disapear and the page is refresh http://jsfiddle.net/76tHv/1/

Comment: because you're using `submit` type `button`. Replace buttons with _anchor_, `<a href="#" class="ui-btn">Button</a>`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/76tHv/2/

Comment: i have tried to replace my button type to button and i have mad a function closePopup and it's work thank you for your answer it was very helpfull for me